# How to draw a Tikz chart of modular files?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a small chart showing a modular C++-program. I don't know where to start.

```
+-------------\  **    +------------\        + compiled src --+
| module.hpp  |\   **  | main.cpp   |\       |                |
+-------------+-+    **+------------+-+      | void func()    |
|               |      | #include "...|  ==> | int main() {   |
| void func();  |    **| int main() { |      |   ...          |
|               |  **  |   ...        |      |                |
+---------------+**    +--------------+      +----------------+
```

The `module.hpp` should visually "go into" the `#include`-line in `main.cpp`, so I thought about connecting lines that I draw as `**`-lines.

I will replace the text in the boxes with a bit better text, and probably add another box to the right for the applied compiler.

I can not think of what should be nodes here.

Comment: you should look into {tikz-uml}

Comment: You can also play with \fbox, \parbox, \left. \right\rbrace and \rarrow and put the whole thing into an equation.  But to do the triangle you need tikz.

Comment: @towi have you found a solution or is this still open?

Comment: @PaulGessler I found a solution but did it a bit different. I think my [current visualization](http://pastebin.com/fEHbbBne) is actually better then what I first planned.

Comment: @towi great! You could either post your solution as a self-answer if you think it will be helpful for future visitors to the site, or close the question if you think the solution is too specific to your situation. It's up to you to decide. :)

Answer (score 2):

For the record, I found a satisfactory solution. I modified a bit how I wanted to display the "inclusion" and I am quite satisfied with it. Just to let you know, if anyone wants to try the same.

[image: modules]

```
%%\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
%%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
%%\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
%%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
%%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{back}
\pgfsetlayers{background,back,main}

\resizebox {\columnwidth} {!} {    % (2) scale to exact column width
\begin{tikzpicture}[
      background rectangle/.style={fill=black!10}, show background rectangle,
]

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw, fill=black!0, very thick,
    rectangle, inner sep=8pt, inner ysep=16pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=black!0, draw, very thick, text=black!100, rectangle, inner xsep=6pt,yshift=7.2pt,right=0pt]
\tikzstyle{modul} =[text=black!100, rectangle, inner sep=6pt]
\tikzstyle{cpp} =[fill=black!0, draw=black!30, thick]
\tikzstyle{hpp} =[fill=black!0, draw, thick]


  \node at (0,0) (main) [modul,cpp] {%
    \begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
      \#include "teil1.hpp" \\ 
      \#include "teil2.hpp" \\ 
      \#include "const.hpp" \\ 
      int main() \{ ... \} 
    \end{minipage}%
  };
  \node[fancytitle,cpp] at (main.north west) {main.cpp};

  \node [below=of main.south east,xshift=-4ex] (teil1hpp) [modul,hpp] {%
    \begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
      int func1(); \\
      static const int M=10;
    \end{minipage}%
  };
  \node[fancytitle,hpp] at (teil1hpp.north west) (a1) {teil1.hpp};

  \node [right=of teil1hpp.north east, anchor=north west] (teil1cpp) [modul,cpp] {%
    \begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
      \#include "teil1.hpp" \\ 
      \#include "{}util.hpp" \\ 
      int func1() \{ ... \};
    \end{minipage}%
  };
  \node[fancytitle,cpp] at (teil1cpp.north west){teil1.cpp};


  \node [below=of teil1hpp,yshift=-12pt] (teil2hpp) [modul,hpp] {%
    \begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
      \#include "{}util.hpp" \\ 
      \#include "const.hpp" \\ 
      int func2(); \\
          int data[Z];
    \end{minipage}%
  };
  \node[fancytitle,hpp] at (teil2hpp.north west) {teil2.hpp};

  \node [right=of teil2hpp.north east, anchor=north west] (teil2cpp) [modul,cpp] {%
    \begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
      \#include "teil2.hpp" \\ 
      int func2() \{ ... \}; \\
          int data[Z] = \{\};
    \end{minipage}%
  };
  \node[fancytitle,cpp] at (teil2cpp.north west) {teil2.cpp};


  \node [below=of teil2hpp] (utilhpp) [modul,hpp] {%
    \begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
      int calcLen();
    \end{minipage}%
  };
  \node[fancytitle,hpp] at (utilhpp.north west) (a2) {util.hpp};

  \node [right=of utilhpp.north east, anchor=north west] (utilcpp) [modul,cpp] {%
    \begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
      \#include "{}util.hpp" \\ 
      \#include "const.hpp" \\ 
      int calcLen() \{ ... \};
    \end{minipage}%
  };
  \node[fancytitle,cpp] at (utilcpp.north west) {util.cpp};

  \node [right=of utilcpp.north east, anchor=north west] (consthpp) [modul,hpp] {%
    \begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
      static const int X=1; \\
      static const int Y=2; \\
      static const int Z=3;
    \end{minipage}%
  };
  \node[fancytitle,hpp] at (consthpp.north west) {const.hpp};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{back}

 \path (main.south west) -- (a1.north west) node[midway] (aa) {};
 \path (main.south west)[xshift=-3ex] |- (aa) node[midway] (aaa) {};
   \draw[ultra thick,draw=black!20] (aaa) -- ([xshift=3ex]aaa -| consthpp.north east);

 \path (teil2hpp.south west) -- (a2.north west) node[midway] (bb) {};
   \draw[ultra thick,draw=black!20] (aaa |- bb) -- ([xshift=3ex]bb -| consthpp.north east);

\begin{scope}[->,thick,black!50]
 \draw[arrows={-triangle 45}]   (main.south west) |- (teil1hpp.west);
 \draw[arrows={-triangle 45}]   (main.south west) |- (teil2hpp)  ;
 \draw[arrows={-triangle 45}]   (main.east) -| ([xshift=1cm]consthpp.north);
 \draw[arrows={-triangle 45}]   (teil1cpp.south west)  -- (utilhpp.north east);
 \draw[arrows={-triangle 45}]   ([yshift=1.1cm]teil2cpp.west)  -- (teil1hpp);
 \draw[arrows={-triangle 45}]   (teil2hpp) edge [out=-20] (consthpp.north west); 
 \draw[arrows={-triangle 45}]   (utilcpp) -- (consthpp);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
 \draw[thick,dashed,black!50]   (teil1cpp.north west) -- (teil1hpp.north east);
 \draw[thick,dashed,black!50]   (teil2cpp.north west) -- (teil2hpp.north east);
 \draw[thick,dashed,black!50]   (utilcpp.north west) -- (utilhpp.north east);
\end{scope}
\end{pgfonlayer}



\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```